# Web Matrix, Data Types, User Registration

Tags: mysql, webmatrix, user-registration

I am using WebMatrix to create a table in my user database.

My [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAkKC8DKN9A) says to use the BOOLEAN data type for the field that determines whether or not the user's registration is active, because it allows the field to be true or false. BOOLEAN is not an option.

What can I use instead to achieve the same result?

Please feel free to ask for clarification. Any help is much appreciated. Even suggestions for other tutorials on creating a user registration / member system would be great. Thank you!

Comment: What data fields are allowed? Using an integer with 0=False, 1=True would certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is "bit" and the default value is 0 (zero) this will be interpreted as false by MS SQL Server 2012. To say it another way the "bool" value in Webmatrix equates to a "bit" value in MS SQL Server 2012.

```
// on the webmatrix side of things
Int UserID = 0; // the users id (usually int)
bool allowed = false;

// the database needs at least 2 fields

int UserID;
bit Allowed;


var db = Database.Open("TheDatabase"); 
// don't forget to set this up in your web.config file.
var TestRecord = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM webpages_Membership WHERE UserID=@0", UserID );

allowed TestRecord.Allowed; 

db.close();
```

This is just a ruff sketch of how to accomplish this... hope it helps